# Правильно ли я формирую массив и как его потом прочитать?

Tags: php, массивы

Пытаюсь сделать формирование массива данных, а потом их вывести js там где мне надо. Но что-то я закопался

```
$json_output = array();
    $result_vk_group_list = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `vk_group_list` WHERE id_cabinet = '4'");

        while($row_vk_group_list = mysql_fetch_array($result_vk_group_list)){

            $result_message_new = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM vk_group_notify WHERE type = 'message_new' and group_id = '".$row_vk_group_list['group_id']."' and status = '0'");
            $cout_message_new = mysql_num_rows($result_message_new);

            $result_comment_new = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM vk_group_notify WHERE (type = 'wall_reply_new' or type = 'photo_comment_new' or type = 'video_comment_new' or type = 'market_comment_new') and group_id = '".$row_vk_group_list['group_id']."' and status = '0'");
            $cout_comment_new = mysql_num_rows($result_comment_new);    

            array_push($json_output, array("id".$row_vk_group_list['group_id']."" => array("message_new"=>"$cout_message_new","comment_new"=>"$cout_comment_new")));




        }




    $user_info = json_encode($json_output);
```

Получается такой массив

```
[{"id73169318":{"message_new":"4","comment_new":"0"}},{"id23916815":{"message_new":"0","comment_new":"2"}}]
```

Как мне прочесть данные например id73169318->message_new?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если вы хотите обращаться к элементам массива по ключу, то вам нужно создавать [ассоциативный массив](http://php.net/manual/ru/language.types.array.php), явно указывая ключи для добавляемых елементов.

Например:

```
$array['key'] = $element;
```

В случае с вашим примером это может выглядеть вот так:

```
$json_output["id".$row_vk_group_list['group_id']] = array("message_new"=>"$cout_message_new","comment_new"=>"$cout_comment_new");
```

вместо `array_push()`.

Такой массив, будучи сериализованным, может быть преобразован в объект на стороне JS. Это позволит обращаться к его элементам напрямую - по ключу.

```
data_object['id73169318'].message_new
```

Добавляя элементы функцией `array_push`, или равнозначной операцией присваивания `$array[] = $element`, вы создаёте обычный массив, ключами которого будут лишь порядковые номера добавляемых элементов. На стороне JS, при таком подходе, для поиска элемента по его `id` потребуется перебирать все элементы массива по-очереди.

Comment: получилось вот так {"id73169318":{"message_new":"39","comment_new":"0"},"id23916815":{"message_new":"0","comment_new":"2"}} только вот как теперь его прочесть запросом js